# row number 0 is out of range 0..-1 returned when using setSingleRowMode libpq

Tags: postgresql, libpq

I was trying to retrieve the row one by one using `PQsetSingleRowMode`. The result set is ok except the last 3 rows are returned with row number 0 is out of range 0..-1

This is my main function:

```
int main(){
/* The code to create connection to the database is fine, so I skipped it */

PQsetnonblocking(conn,1);
  const char *DML_statement="select * from itsdb.PvKeyword";
  int status = PQsendQuery(conn,DML_statement);
  int isSingleMode=PQsetSingleRowMode(conn);
  res = PQgetResult(conn);
  cout << "print out 1 if it is single mode: " << isSingleMode;
  char* field1;
  char* field2;
  char* field3;

  while (PQgetResult(conn)!= NULL || PQresultStatus(res)!=PGRES_TUPLES_OK || PQresultStatus(res)==PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE)
  {
        res = PQgetResult(conn);
        field1 = PQgetvalue(res,0,0);
        field2 = PQgetvalue(res,0,1);
        field3 = PQgetvalue(res,0,2);
        cout << field1 << "," << field2 << "," << field3 << endl;
        PQclear(res);
  }
```

Result set:

```
david,3,male
natalie,1,female
daniel,1,,female
row number 0 is out of range 0..-1
row number 0 is out of range 0..-1
row number 0 is out of range 0..-1
```

I changed it to a do/while and it worked.

```
char* field1;
char* field2;
char* field3;

do {
  if (PQresultStatus(res)==PGRES_TUPLES_OK)
     break;
  res = PQgetResult(conn);
  field1 = PQgetvalue(res,0,0);
  field2 = PQgetvalue(res,0,1);
  field3 = PQgetvalue(res,0,2);
  cout << field1 << "," << field2 << "," << field3 << endl;
  PQclear(res);
} while (PQgetResult(conn)!= NULL || PQresultStatus(res)==PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following condition in the while loop:

```
while (res != nullptr && PQresultStatus(res) == PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE)
```

Missing the `PQresultStatus(res) == PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE` condition leads to retrieving one extra row after the last valid one.